# ajax logout redirect

Tags: php, ajax

```
public static function logout(){
        DB::query("DELETE FROM webchat_users WHERE name = '".DB::esc($_SESSION['user']['name'])."'");


        $_SESSION = array();
        unset($_SESSION);

        return array('status' => 1);
        window.location.replace("http://domain.com/index.php");

    }
```

This is the code I use to logout of a chat window, that is ran using AJAX. I'm just wondering if there is a way so it will do a redirect when the button is pressed. This is the procedure that is ran on.click. I've currently experimented with `window.location.` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

How would I do this?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `session_destroy()` or something?

Comment: I think you are mixing PHP and JavaScript code here.

Comment: Must've missed the section on `window.location.replace()` in the PHP manual :)

Comment: I know it's `header (location..` in php :')

Comment: the php way didn't do the trick either

Comment: Since this is an AJAX request, you need JavaScript to redirect the browser.  If you redirect from PHP, it will just redirect the AJAX call, not the browser.

Comment: @Rocket can this be be done within the AJAX request

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to use `window.location` after the AJAX call is done (in its callback).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's an Ajax call you cannot redirect the user. If you use `header('Location: ...')` you will redirect the Ajax requestion, which will have no effect on the user.

You can either:

1. redirect the user to the logout page, instead of sending an Ajax request and use `header('Location: ...')` to send him back to your home page
2. Use an ajax call, but the `window.location` must be done in the javascript par **after** the ajax call. In the `onSuccess` event for instance

Comment: `case 'logout':
   header('Location: http://domain.com/index.php');
  break;`  ..it doesn't redirect :/

Comment: @Rsmithy Is this in your PHP?

Comment: @Rsmithy My answer explicitly stated that you *cannot* redirect a user from an Ajax call. Why don't you do the redirection in Javascript after the Ajax call is completed?

Comment: It's on the handler.. the functions that run are on a separate php file